# Android Studio Doesn't show the option to Download Different API Version

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know if this question is duplicate or not. I try to google it for around 2 hours and still not found the real solution.

Can you help me guys on this. Before resetting my computer, my android studio has a lot of API version installed on my PC but after i restart it and re install android studio. only API 27 and API 28 is showing. I don't know how to show the other version or how can i download it. I tried to uninstall it and re install the old version android studio but still not showing. I don't know how can i fix this. Please help me. Thank you. 
Image is shown below for your reference

[image: Android Studio Different API]

**UPDATE**

in SD Update site

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the `SDK Update Sites` tab?

Comment: only 2 links, let me update it and display it also

Comment: Press "Show Package Details" and see if it brings anything useful up.

Comment: Also if you go to the AVD Manager, you could find a virtual device with the API you want and install that device. It'll come with the API for it.

Comment: I already click "Show Package Details" but only the details of API 27 and 28 is shown

Comment: Yeah you're missing a ton of update sites here. Let me see if I can dig out a list you can easily import...

Comment: Thanks. I really need to fix this. My project deadline is next week.

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this? and can you paste the full URL for the update site you do have? also, hover over the red bubble on the listing and share what that warning is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a listing of all the update sites i have in Android Studio:

Android Repository  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml

Android System Images   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml

Android TV System Images    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml

Android Wear System Images  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml

Android Wear for China System Images    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-cn/sys-img2-1.xml

Glass Development Kit, Google Inc.  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml

Google API add-on System Images https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml

Google API with Playstore System Images https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml

Google Inc. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml

Intel HAXM  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I update this all. Is API level 26 and below will display on my android studio?

Comment: tough to say, I am digging into some reading on why those would be missing from your Android Studio, maybe it was a bad upgrade? I assume at one point you did have the SDK. I wonder if you restart/clear android studio cache if that would help